# WPF combobox items list/context menu rendered behind parent

Tags: wpf, combobox, contextmenu

If the ItemSource property of a combo box has been set, why could clicking on the drop down botton of a combobox not display the list of available items?  This may be related but within the same control, any context menu is displayed behind the user control:

The XAML for this control is as follows:

```
 <Border Name="Border" Padding="5">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ScrollViewer.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>            
            </ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>                          
                    <Grid Margin="5,4,0,4" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="labelColumn1" />
                            <ColumnDefinition  SharedSizeGroup="labelColumn2" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="dataEntryColumn" />
                            <ColumnDefinition  Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition  SharedSizeGroup="labelColumn2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="dataEntryColumn" />
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="0" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition MinHeight="23" />
                            <RowDefinition MinHeight="23" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="Geometry Type" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>                       
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Margin="6,1,0,1"   Grid.Row="0" Width="150"  
                                  Name="cmboGeometryTypes"   
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding GeometryType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"   
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"                                   
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="1"                                      
                                 />

                        <TextBlock Text="Symbol Type" 
                                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ComboBox
                            Name="cmboSymbolEditors"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SymbolEditorViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"   
                            DisplayMemberPath="Alias" 
                            Width="150"
                            Grid.Column="3" 
                            Margin="6,1,0,1" 
                            Grid.Row="1"                            
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="1"  />               
                </Grid>

                <Label Padding="10,0,0,0" Margin="10,0,0,3" Style="{StaticResource fadingLabelSeperatorStlye}" Grid.Row="1">
                    Editor
                </Label>
                <local:SymbologyEditorControl x:Name="editor" Grid.Row="2"/>                               
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
```

and the effect I am observing is illustrated below[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: first of all, have you tried adding a margin so you can see if it really is behind the rest of the UI or if it isn't drawn at all

Comment: No, I have not done this.  However, if I use a ListBox, I do see the list of available items that the combobox is not displaying.  Given the related problem with context menus, I am suspecting combo box list is being drawn behind parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a common WPF bug that caused this behavior of any Popup type UI displaying in back instead of topmost so that may be what you're seeing. I haven't seen the issue in a while but I'm not sure if it was fixed or not. It's related to bad video drivers so you might see it only on certain machines and not all the time.

There was a hotfix available from MS support but it might be easier to just switch your application to use software rendering instead.

Comment: You are corrext that it does not happen on very machine application is installed.  Will look for hotfix, thanks.